# How to send parameters onChange

Tags: reactjs

I have this code:

```
export default function CreateGame(){
    const classes = useStyles()
    const [questions, setQuestions] = React.useState([{
        question: '',
        answer: '',
        score: '',
        age: ''
    }])
    const HandleField = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target)
    }
    return(
        <Card>
            <CardContent>
                <Typography>
                    Add Questions
                </Typography>
                
                {questions.map((value, index) =>
                    <Grid container spacing={1}>
                        <Grid item lg={2}>
                            <TextField
                                value={value['question']}
                                key={index}
                                label='Question'
                                variant='outlined'
                                onChange={HandleField} />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item lg={2}>
                            <TextField
                                value={value['answer']}
                                key={index}
                                label='Answer'
                                variant='outlined'
                                onChange={HandleField} />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item lg={2}>
                            <TextField
                                value={value['score']}
                                label='Score'
                                key={index}
                                variant='outlined'
                                onChange={HandleField} />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item lg={5}>
                            <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
                                <InputLabel id="age">Age</InputLabel>
                                <Select
                                    labelId="age"
                                    id="age"
                                    label="Age"
                                    key="index"
                                    value={value['age']}
                                >
                                    <MenuItem value=""><em>None</em></MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
                                </Select>
                            </FormControl>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                )}
            </CardContent>
            <Button>Add</Button>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

As you can see, on my TextField I have `onChange={HandleField}`. I want to be able to send parameters to `HandleField` since I need to use they key(index) and another value I need to send per field. Is this possible? Or, if I can't send parameters, maybe there is another way I can get that index value when my TextField's value changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Update `handleField` to accept the additional arguments.

```
const HandleField = (event, index, ...args) => {
  console.log(event.target)
}
```

Then pass them when attaching the handler

```
onChange={e => HandleField(e, index, 'arg1', /* etc... */)}
```

Tip: You can curry the additional parameters after the event object, which can simplify the attaching a bit. By creating a curried handler it takes the arguments at runtime and returns a function that accepts the event object. This avoids the anonymous function.

```
const HandleField = (index, ...args) => event => {
  console.log(event.target)
}

...

onChange={HandleField(index, 'arg1', /* etc... */)}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The part I was missing was the `onChange={e => HandleField(e, index, 'arg1', /* etc... */)}` I thought I just had to do `HandleField(event, index, ....)` Will accept answer as soon as it is allowed!

Comment: @plasmy I added a tip about using a curried function to actually do nearly what you were trying.